# Async read operations from child via pipe returns nulls before exit

Tags: c, asynchronous, select, pipe, waitpid

I made a program which creates a child that calls a simple system command (in this case the unix list folder contents command - ls). Then the parent is to perform other house-keeping functions while waiting for the child to finish and while showing the output the child produces in real time.

So far everything is successful except for one problem: After all the data is read and printed, I am seeing a lot of blank data until the child officially exits.

This is my output:

```
Got: total 120
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Dec 28 17:
Got: 10 .
drwxr-xr-x 65 root root  4096 Dec 27 19:03 ..
Got: 
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8518 Dec 27 19:25 7seg.b
Got: mp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  9636 Dec 28 17:10 a.ou
Got: t
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7398 Dec 27 19:25 butto
Got: n.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11278 Dec 27 19:36 c
Got: able.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1444 Dec 28 17:1
Got: 0 fork1.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18190 Dec 27 19:
Got: 29 lcd.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   192 Dec 28 01
Got: :38 lcd.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10836 Dec 28 
Got: 16:02 lcdui.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7718 Dec 27
Got:  19:26 led.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9026 Dec 2
Got: 7 21:24 mygui.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8178 Dec 
Got: 27 19:33 uc.bmp

Got: 
Got: 
Got: 
Got: 
Got: 
Got:
```

But in the real output, the last line is repeated roughly 100 times.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

//Setup child read and write file handle named parr and parw respectively
//and parent read and write file handle named  to parr and parw respectively

#define kidr wrp[0]
#define kidw rdp[1]
#define parw wrp[1]
#define parr rdp[0]


int main(){
  //setup and start pipes
  int wrp[2],rdp[2];
  if (pipe(wrp) == -1 || pipe(rdp) == -1){printf("ERROR: cant run pipes.\n");return -1;}

  //Start fork
  pid_t f=fork();

  if (f > 0){
  int wstat; //wait state data
  char buff[100]; //our data buffer
  close(kidr); //we are parent so close child handles
  close(kidw);
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set readfds;
  tv.tv_sec = 1;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;
  while(1){

      //process other async events here

      pid_t wpid=waitpid(-1,&wstat,WNOHANG);
      if (wpid==-1){printf("Wait PID error\n");break;}
      if (wpid > 0){printf("Children closed OK\n");break;}
      //Process data only when child data is readable via pipe
      FD_ZERO(&readfds);FD_SET(parr, &readfds);
      select(parr+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv); 
      if(FD_ISSET(parr, &readfds)){
        memset(buff,0,99);
        read(parr, buff, 50);
        printf("Got: %s\n", buff); //still reaches here even after child terminates
      }
  }
  //close everything and exit
  close(parr);
  close(parw);
  return 0;
  }
  if (f==0){
  //Child mode.
  //Close parents
  close(parr);close(parw);
  //make stdio as child handles
  dup2(kidr,STDIN_FILENO);dup2(kidw,STDOUT_FILENO);
  //close old child handles
  close(kidw);close(kidr);
  execlp("/usr/bin/ls","ls","-al",NULL);
  //We shouldn't get here unless 'ls' command isnt found
  printf("Exec failed\n");
  _exit(-1);
  }

  if (f==-1){
  //If fork() doesnt work...
  printf("Fork error\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing arbitrary size reads (50) on lines that are close to 50 characters. I would suggest to do line-based input, like `fgets()`, or do some internal buffering.

Comment: Do _not_ stop if `waitpid` says child has finished--just note it [set a variable] and continue (but stop calling `waitpid` if the child has finished). Check the return value from `read` and stop if it is <= 0. I made these changes and it works fine.

Comment: Ok I did solve the problem with checking that the value from read = 0.